# How Do I Change Unit Names?

Tags: civilization-5

Is it possible to change unit names such as "Giant Death Robot" to something else?  I understsnd how to rename units, but would like to change what appears  in the production queue.  And can messages such as "People Who Smile the Most" be rewritten?  I was surprised to see such casual language and prefer the more traditional.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to create a mod for Civilization 5 which changes texts. The method I would recommend is to [setup a new language](http://wiki.2kgames.com/civ5/index.php/Mods:AddingNewLanguage) for civilization, and replace and strings you want changed in there. That way you can always switch back to English when needed, and you have a backup of original texts.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Xenox's answer I was able to change "People Who Smile the Most" and others following this path:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\sid meier's civilization v\assets\Gameplay\XML\NewText\en_US`.

Use notepad to open the file, edit the changes, save and run the game.  The same applies to "Giant Death Robot" (under units) which became "MechWarrior."  The name seemed appropriate and is much more menacing.

Comment: Xenox's answer didn't suit my purposes. God bless him and his efforts. But editing my response violates the principles of the First Amendment which Canada never adopted.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it - @AnnaLear was just trying to insert more specific language - if someone else were to post on your question, for instance, "your answer" would be left ambiguous. That said, there is *nothing* wrong with a self-answer!

Comment: @GaryCole Collaborative editing is something that's [encouraged](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#editing) on this site, but I do apologize for misinterpreting your answer. I thought Xenox's answer got you on the right track. If you just want to thank him in general, the best way to thank him would be to upvote his answer and (optionally) leave a comment. You can also roll back my edit by clicking on the edit timestamp to access the revision history.

Comment: I knew as I read the response that there must be a better way, that the text could be easily edited.  And I found the answer due to the fire in my belly.  And thankfully, it was ignited by Xenox's response.  Thank you to him and this site.